# Remove newline characters that appear between curly brackets

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm currently writing a text processing script which contains static text and variable values (surrounded by curly brackets). I need to be able to strip out newline characters but only if they appear between the curly brackets:

`Some text\nwith a {variable\n} value"`

to:

`Some text\nwith a {variable} value"`

Further down in the processing I'm already doing this:

`re.sub(r'\{.*?\}', '(.*)', text, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)`

But I'm not sure how to target just the newline character and not the entirely of the curly bracket pair. There is also the possibility of multiple newlines:

`Some text\nwith a {variable\n\n\n} value"`

---

Using Python 3.x

Comment: The replacement pattern can only contain special replacement constructs and literals.

Comment: Either use an assertion and replace with an empty string `''` or group the replacement and use a back reference in the replacement string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may pass the match object to a lambda in a `re.sub` and replace all newlines inside `{...}`:

```
import re
text = 'Some text\nwith a {variable\n} value"'
print(re.sub(r'{.*?}', lambda m: m.group().replace("\n", ""), text, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

See [online Python 3 demo](http://ideone.com/ElV2ph)

Note that you do not need `re.MULTILINE` flag with this regex as it has no `^`/`$` anchors to redefine the behavior of, and you do not need to escape `{` and `}` in the current expression (without excessive backslashes, regexps look cleaner).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have un-nested, balanced brackets you can use this lookahead regex to replace newline between `{...}`:

```
>>> s = "Some text\nwith a {variable\n} value"
>>> print re.sub(r'\n(?=[^{}]*})', '', s)
Some text
with a {variable} value
```

`(?=[^{}]*})` is lookahead to assert we have a closing `}` ahead of newline without matching a `{` or `}` before closing `}`.